# Html CSS Bootstrap Modal not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am a beginner in programming i'm stuck with a problem..my modal is not working the modal is displaying in the page not in the popup..I desperately need the solution..it would be great if someone can help me get out of this problem.Here is my code snippet..

```
                                    <div class="info-box">
                                    <h3>M Saifur Rahman</h3>
                                    <span class="instructor-profession">Director,Business Development</span>

                                    <div class="divider"></div>


<center><button type="button" class="btn btn info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Read More</button></center>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>`enter code here`
          <h4 class="modal-title">M Saifur Rahman,PMP</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I am putting the links and scripts here..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: "I am a beginner in programming i'm stuck with a problem", when this problem has something to do with HTML and JS I highly recommend to check the console in the browser. In most cases you will be able to get where the problem is coming from in this case there will be something like `Bootstrap requires Jquery...`. Just for the next time ;)

Comment: change the position of script, make sure you import bootstrap.min.js after you add jquery.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the position of the `jquery` importing in your html page,that is import jquery first then the bootstrap js because `Bootstrapjs` require `jquery` to run.

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
 <div class="info-box">
                                    <h3>M Saifur Rahman</h3>
                                    <span class="instructor-profession">Director,Business Development</span>

                                    <div class="divider"></div>


<center><button type="button" class="btn btn info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Read More</button></center>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">M Saifur Rahman,PMP</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Here goes the body content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but my problem has not been fully solved yet. I put the modal contents and header contents, the body contents show but the header content(Name) does not show up.can you tell me whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Saif,

U have to define java script for opening the modal.   For ex: if u want to open modal on button click then u will define commands to open on button

$('#online_exam').click(function(){  

    $("#myModal").modal('show');
})

Comment: Oh boy. Please edit you answer. If you hope to receive any up votes for this you will be disappointed

Comment: even though thats some mad skill code you got there, I still think you should use "you" instead of "U", format the code properly and explain things a little more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Just place the https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js before https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js. you You should load jquery first because bootstrap use jquery features.

Comment: two people already pointed that out. Why would think its a good Idea to post the same answer again?